# Can every problem in Theory of Computation be stated as undecidable, by writing a reduction from Halting Problem?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

Let us consider the problem that
Whether a given Turing Machine M, has at least 481 states.

Since the number of states of M can be read off from the encoding of M. We can build a Turing machine that, given the encoding of M written on its input tape, counts the number of states of M and accepts or rejects depending on whether the number is at least 481.

(Source : Discussion in Automata and Computability by Dexter Kozen)

But, let us forget this for some time, and try to write reduction from a Halting problem.

HP # x -> Halting problem instance

We are constructing a machine 'R'

Input to R:  A machine description M

What 'R' does::
First runs HP on x, if halts, then check whether M has 481 states, if yes accept, else reject.

```
L(R) = {
                 Set of all descriptions M, which has at least 481 states  ::::  If HP halts on x
                 Phi  ::: If HP doesn't halt on x
       }
```

Doesn't this hold as a reduction from Halting Problem to the problem mentioned above?

Or I am doing some wrong in the process of the reduction?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is a "halting problem instance"? What do you mean by "first runs $HP$ on $x$"? What is $HP$ and what is $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Just because a problem can be reduced from the halting problem does not make the original problem undecideable. A problem is decideable if there exists an algorithm that solves the problem. That means that a problem is *undecideable* if there does not exist any algorithm that solves it. In other words, a problem is undecideable if, for **every** algorithm, it is true that the algorithm does not solve the problem.

The existence of *some* algorithm that does not solve the problem in no way shows that the problem is undecideable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I understood the definition of reduction in the wrong way.

The reduction is to be made from a language (set) or essentially a problem of that. (A set can be represented as a problem that, given an entity, whether that entity belongs to that set or not) to another language.

So first of all, writing the language that we need.

`L481 = { M | M has at least 481 states }`

Corresponding problem::

`Given a Turing machine M, whether M has at least 481 states i.e. whether M belongs to L481 or not.`

So in this case I need to do

`Halting Problem <=m L481`

So we need to map between the **instances** of first language to second language, in such a way that if the mapped instance is decidable to be a member of L481 or not, we can decide whether the instance of Halting problem say M#x, M halts on x or not.

So,

```
M#x |-> N
```

The reduction algorithm that we need to pose:

```
if M halts on x <=> N has at least 481 states
if M doesn't halt on x <=> N doesn't have at least 481 states
```

This absolutely can not be true, as a machine N has fixed number of states in its finite control, irrespective of any other things, other than the description of that.

So, this reduction is false.

What I have done, earlier in my question, was I have written reduction in the wrong way, that I have to write a machine, that takes some instances and decide on them whether that belongs to the L481 or not. (essentially I was trying to write a decider, for a problem which is undecidable).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Your reduction goes in the wrong way. You should reduce *to* the halting problem and not from. So, the correct reduction would be something like this:

1. I want to solve MY PROBLEM.
2. I think I cannot do it, so I will prove the following: If I can solve MY PROBLEM, I can solve HP.
3. I assume I can create a Turing machine for MY PROBLEM.
4. I somehow modify an arbitrary input to HP, so that it can be input to Turing machine for MY PROBLEM.
5. I get an answer from the Turing machine and decode it back, so that I have an answer for the original input to HP.
6. The answer should not exist, thus, my assumption 3 is wrong.